# How to construct and plot the following accumulated list?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list, say it is

```
a = {1,3,3.2,3.9,4,4.4,4.9,5,7,8}
```

To get the accumulate:

```
acc = Accumlate[a]
```

I want to plot the number of elements less than or equal to a certain element against the accumulated value of the list elements.
The pairs should look like (`acc[[i]]`, number of elements less than `a[[i]]`). For instance, (1, 1), (4, 2), (7.2,3), etc.

Then I want to take the derivative of the plot to plot it as well.

Comment: The plotting is not a problem see `ListPlot`. Also, if you want a derivative you will have to define this as you don't have a continuous function. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The plot is an issue when I have very large number of pairs like 1000 pairs. I am trying to do it using ListPlot and a Do loop but it does not work. I am doing: ListLinePlot[{Do[Print[{acc[[i]], Count[a[[i]]}], {i, 10}]}] but it only prints the pairs for me with an empty plot.

Comment: Your combined use of `Do` and `Print` doesn't do what you expect. `Print` merely prints to the screen but does not build a list; use `Table` instead. Also, `Count` is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no duplicate elements in the list, and that the list is sorted in ascending order:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Accumulate[a], Range[Length[a]]}]]
```

If the list isn't sorted, you should replace `Accumulate[a]` with `Accumulate[Sort[a]]`.

[image]

If you need the derivative, it may be easier to first construct an interpolating function. Here I make the interpolation linear (`InterpolationOrder -> 1`) but you can change this. You can get the above plot with `Plot[b[x], {x, 1, Total[a]}]` and the first-derivative plot with

```
b = Interpolation[Transpose[{Accumulate[Sort[a]], Range[Length[a]]}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[b'[x], {x, 1, Total[a]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
a = {1, 3, 3.2, 3.9, 4, 4.4, 4.9, 5, 7, 8};
acc = Accumulate@a;
aa[x_] := Length@Select[a, # <= a[[x]] &];
list = Transpose[{acc, aa /@ Range@Length@a}]
ListLinePlot@list
```

> {{1,1},{4,2},{7.2,3},{11.1,4},{15.1,5},{19.5,6},{24.4,7},{29.4,8},{36.4,9},{44.4,10}}

[image]

Comment: The y-axis should represent the number of elements less than or equal a[[i]] not the element itself.

Comment: @Hamza fixed....